# apache wsgi_mod fails to run on python 3.10

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am developing a django app using django 4 and python 3.10.
I had a server using apache and mod_wsgi, that used to run an old app using python3.8.

I've created a virtual env from 3.10. Command line manage.py is working well.

I've changed apache's conf:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess my_app310 python-path=/home/ubuntu/my_app310:/home/ubuntu/venv/my_app310/lib/python3.10/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup my_app310
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/my_app310/my_app310/wsgi.py
```

But I keep getting:

```
[mpm_event:notice] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=1724834): Failed to exec Python script file '/home/ubuntu/my_app310/my_app310/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=1724834): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/my_app310/my_app310/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error]     File "/home/ubuntu/venv/my_app310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 10, in <module>
[wsgi:error]       import zoneinfo
[wsgi:error] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zoneinfo'
```

Which suggest that something is running using python3.8 and not python3.10 (mod_wsgi?). What am I missing?

Comment: The author of mod_wsgi says that mod_wsgi does not work with Python 3.10. https://twitter.com/GrahamDumpleton/status/1402398072441753601

Comment: @azalea Reading through the mod_wsgi issue [list](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/747), it sounds like Python3.10.2 fixes it.

Answer (score 6):

to configure apache2 with a certain Python Version just do the following:

1. go into your virtual_env that you have created with Python3.10
2. $ pip install mod_wsgi
3. $ mod_wsgi-express module-config

you get an output like

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "..../lib/python3.10/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py310.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
SSGIPythonHome "..."
```

4. copy the 2 lines into /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
5. restart apache2
   you should see something like

```
[mpm_event:notice] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.10 config .....
```

Comment: I didn't compile it, I've installed it (libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3).

Comment: Depends on how that libapache2... package has been compiled. I would recommend to install mod_wsgi as explained by th author himself on the source page https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi

Comment: I changed the answer above

Answer (score 0):

WSGI Clearly says that `File "/home/ubuntu/venv/my_app310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py",` given this path has no module named zoneinfo try importing module into your python virtual environment.
Example:
pip install (module)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, zoneinfo is part of python since 3.9. I am not supposed to install it.